# Add offset to DeviceOrientationControls in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions, device-orientation

I'm trying to add an offset to the camera after `deviceControls.update();` command. I used `DeviceOrientationControls` as shown in this [first example.](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_deviceorientation)

The offset will be the result of a drag gesture, as presents in [this example.](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular)

When I multiply the 2 quaternions (I have tried a x b and b x a), the final result is not correct.

Here is my operation :

```
const m1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
m1.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(), camera.target, THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp.clone());

const quater = new THREE.Quaternion();
quater.setFromRotationMatrix(m1);

const finalQuater = new THREE.Quaternion();
finalQuater.multiplyQuaternions(quater, camera.quaternion);

camera.quaternion.copy(finalQuater);
```

`camera.target` is my final drag target (Vector3), and `camera.quaternion` has been set by `deviceControls.update()` and is equals to the camera orientation, according to the device gyroscope.

Thanks for your help

Update : I have tried to changer rotate order, same problem. I think it is due to the origin change after the device orientation update, but can't find how to solve.

Comment: See if the [version in the r.76dev branch](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js) has the flexibility you need.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeviceOrientationControls` now has a property `alphaOffsetAngle`, and a method

```
controls.updateAlphaOffsetAngle( angle ); // angle is in radians
```

that will rotate the scene around the three.js 'Y' axis.

three.js r.77

Comment: Thanks, I added the same function for other axis and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var rotY = 0;
    var rotX = 0;    
    function setObjectQuaternion(quaternion, alpha, beta, gamma, orient) {
        var zee = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
        var euler = new THREE.Euler();
        var q0 = new THREE.Quaternion();
        var q1 = new THREE.Quaternion( -Math.sqrt( 0.5 ), 0, 0, Math.sqrt( 0.5 ) ); // - PI/2 around the x-axis

        if (screenOrientation == 0) {
            var vectorFingerY = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ); 
            var fingerQY = new THREE.Quaternion();
            fingerQY.setFromAxisAngle ( vectorFingerY, -rotX );
        }else if (screenOrientation == 180) {
            var vectorFingerY = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ); 
            var fingerQY = new THREE.Quaternion();
            fingerQY.setFromAxisAngle ( vectorFingerY, rotX );
        }else if (screenOrientation == 90) {
            var vectorFingerY = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); 
            var fingerQY = new THREE.Quaternion();
            fingerQY.setFromAxisAngle ( vectorFingerY, rotX );
        }else if (screenOrientation == -90) {
            var vectorFingerY = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); 
            var fingerQY = new THREE.Quaternion();
            fingerQY.setFromAxisAngle ( vectorFingerY, -rotX );
        }
        q1.multiply( fingerQY );

        euler.set( beta, alpha, - gamma, 'YXZ' );                       // 'ZXY' for the device, but 'YXZ' for us
        quaternion.setFromEuler( euler );                               // orient the device
        quaternion.multiply( q1 );                                      // camera looks out the back of the device, not the top
        quaternion.multiply( q0.setFromAxisAngle( zee, - orient ) );    // adjust for screen orientation
    };

    function update(camera) {
        if (window.orientation !== undefined && window.orientation !== null) screenOrientation = window.orientation; 

        var alpha  = deviceOrientation.alpha ? THREE.Math.degToRad( deviceOrientation.alpha ) : 0; // Z
        var beta   = deviceOrientation.beta  ? THREE.Math.degToRad( deviceOrientation.beta  ) : 0; // X'
        var gamma  = deviceOrientation.gamma ? THREE.Math.degToRad( deviceOrientation.gamma ) : 0; // Y''
        var orient = screenOrientation       ? THREE.Math.degToRad( screenOrientation       ) : 0; // O
        setObjectQuaternion( camera.quaternion, alpha, beta, gamma, orient );
    };
```

add this to your init 
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

```
            renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function (e) {
                if (controls) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    tempX = e.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
                    tempY = e.touches[ 0 ].pageY;
                }
            }, false );
            renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', function (e) {
                if (controls) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    rotY += THREE.Math.degToRad((tempX - e.touches[ 0 ].pageX)/4);
                    rotX += THREE.Math.degToRad((tempY - e.touches[ 0 ].pageY)/4);

                    mesh.quaternion.copy(MeshStartQY);
                    var vectorFingerY = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); 
                    var fingerQY = new THREE.Quaternion();
                    fingerQY.setFromAxisAngle ( vectorFingerY, rotY );

                    mesh.quaternion.multiply(fingerQY);

                    tempX = e.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
                    tempY = e.touches[ 0 ].pageY;
                }
            }, false );
```

Comment: `new THREE.Quaternion();` - Create single instances of `Quaternion` and `Vector` and reuse them. That is what closures are for.